# How to turn monadic into dyadic data in R?

Tags: r

**NOTE: This is a modified version of [How do I turn monadic data into dyadic data in R (country-year into pair-year)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33481645/2572423)**

I have data organized by country-year, with a ID for a dyadic relationship. I want to organize this by dyad-year.

Here is how my data is organized:

```
   dyadic_id country_codes year
1          1           200 1990
2          1            20 1990
3          1           200 1991
4          1            20 1991
5          1           200 1991
6          1           300 1991
7          1           300 1991
8          1            20 1991
9          2           300 1990
10         2            10 1990
11         3           100 1990
12         3            10 1990
13         4           500 1991
14         4           200 1991
```

Here is how I want the data to be:

```
  dyadic_id_want country_codes_1 country_codes_2 year_want
1              1             200              20      1990
2              1             200              20      1991
3              1             200             300      1991
4              1             300              20      1991
5              2             300              10      1990
6              3             100              10      1990
7              4             500             200      1991
```

Here is reproducible code:

```
dyadic_id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
country_codes<-c(200,20,200,20,200,300,300,20,300,10,100,10,500,200)
year<-c(1990,1990,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1990,1990,1990,1990,1991,1991)
mydf<-as.data.frame(cbind(dyadic_id,country_codes,year))


dyadic_id_want<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4)
country_codes_1<-c(200,200,200,300,300,100,500)
country_codes_2<-c(20,20,300,20,10,10,200)
year_want<-c(1990,1991,1991,1991,1990,1990,1991)
my_df_i_want<-as.data.frame(cbind(dyadic_id_want,country_codes_1,country_codes_2,year_want))
```

This is a unique problem since there are more than one country that participate in each event (noted by a dyadic_id).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn monadic data into dyadic data in R (country-year into pair-year)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481645/how-do-i-turn-monadic-data-into-dyadic-data-in-r-country-year-into-pair-year)

Comment: No, this is different since there are more than one country that are associated with each dyadic id.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it very similar to [akrun's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481645/how-do-i-turn-monadic-data-into-dyadic-data-in-r-country-year-into-pair-year) for `dplyr`. Unfortunately I'm not well versed enough in `data.table` to help you with that part, and I'm sure others may have better solution to this one.

Basically for the `mutate(ind=...)` portion you need to be a little more clever on how you construct this indicator so that it is unique and will lead to the same result that you're looking for. For my solution, I notice that since you have groups of two, then your indicator should just have `modulus` operator attached to it.

```
ind=paste0('country_codes', ((row_number()+1) %% 2+1))
```

Then you need an indentifier for each group of two which again can be constructed using the similar idea.

```
ind_row = ceiling(row_number()/2)
```

Then you can proceed as normal in the code.

The full code is as follows:

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(dyadic_id, year) %>%
  mutate(ind=paste0('country_codes', ((row_number()+1) %% 2+1)), 
         ind_row = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
  spread(ind, country_codes) %>% 
  select(-ind_row)
#  dyadic_id year country_codes1 country_codes2
#1         1 1990            200             20
#2         1 1991            200             20
#3         1 1991            200            300
#4         1 1991            300             20
#5         2 1990            300             10
#6         3 1990            100             10
#7         4 1991            500            200
```

All credit to akrun's solution though.